# Speed Comparison Hard Drive( Speficilally NTFS and EXT Linux)

Tags: ntfs, ext

**How would I measure the speed of my hard drive for tons of different files?**
(I would like to create a chart for the NTFS and the ext file systems)

I'm planning to use NTFS for my home directory so I would like to know speed differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there a speed chart comparing NTFS and ext file systems?

> just finished moving data from an NTFS (sda5 partition to a spare drive and then formatting the partition to EXT3 with gparted and then moved the data back across from the spare drive to the newly formatted partition (sda5).
>   but before i did i (non scientifically) benchmarked the partition before and after the format with the same data copied back across after the format.
>
> before as NTFS:

```
Version  1.03       ------Sequential Output------ --Sequential Input- --Random-
                    -Per Chr- --Block-- -Rewrite- -Per Chr- --Block-- --Seeks--
Machine        Size K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP  /sec %CP
Desktop          2G 10018  26 32232   7 11824   3 19638  45 30244   3  93.3   0
                    ------Sequential Create------ --------Random Create--------
                    -Create-- --Read--- -Delete-- -Create-- --Read--- -Delete--
              files  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP
                 16  2652   5 12663   5  4661   5  3237   5 14359  10  4434   6
Desktop,2G,10018,26,32232,7,11824,3,19638,45,30244,3,93.3,0,16,2652,5,12663,5,4661,5,3237,5,14359,10,4434,6
```

> and after as EXT3:

```
Version  1.03       ------Sequential Output------ --Sequential Input- --Random-
                    -Per Chr- --Block-- -Rewrite- -Per Chr- --Block-- --Seeks--
Machine        Size K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP K/sec %CP  /sec %CP
Desktop          2G 17625  48 31046   8 12952   3 23815  52 32382   3 111.2   0
                    ------Sequential Create------ --------Random Create--------
                    -Create-- --Read--- -Delete-- -Create-- --Read--- -Delete--
              files  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP  /sec %CP
                 16 25847  46 +++++ +++ +++++ +++ +++++ +++ +++++ +++ +++++ +++
Desktop,2G,17625,48,31046,8,12952,3,23815,52,32382,3,111.2,0,16,25847,46,+++++,+++,+++++,+++,+++++,+++,+++++,+++,+++++,+++
```

Source [ntfs vs ext3 benchmarks](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=364031)

---

#### Further Reading

- [On Benchmarking Popular File Systems](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~jzwang/pub/fbench.pdf) (link to PDF)

Comment: Do you mind explaining the results a little?  I don't understand at first look.

Comment: As far as I can tell it shows EXT3 is faster. You may find the link in the "Further Reading" section more understandable - it shows real graphs.

Comment: According to the ubuntu link "The above test used a TWO years old, BETA NTFS-3G driver. Today NTFS-3G is often much faster than ext3, especially when transferring very huge files. Ext3 fragments very badly compared to NTFS. Ext4 will solve this problem." +1 but I don't know what the right answer is still.

Comment: I don't either. You can probably search google as well as I can ... the question will probably get closed as off-topic anyway ...

Comment: What if I ask how to measure the speed of a hard drive is that on topic?

Comment: Probably, yes...